# Stuck in ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘XXXXX’

Tags: r, compilation

I am trying to install Arch R on my newly upgraded Debian 10 PC (my R version is 4.1.0).  It stucks at installing support package "DirichletMultinomial".

dirichlet_fit_main.c: In function ‘optimise_lambda_k’:
dirichlet_fit_main.c:221:9: **error: ‘gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_vector_bfgs2’ undeclared (first use in this function)**; did you mean ‘gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_vector_bfgs’?
T = gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_vector_bfgs2;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_vector_bfgs
dirichlet_fit_main.c:221:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: dirichlet_fit_main.o] Error 1
**ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘DirichletMultinomial’**

Does anyone have similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a very similar issue when installing ArchR on R 4.1.0. It seems like your issue might relate to the version of GSL that you have installed. The current stable version is version 2.7, and I re-installed it using the following code in terminal:

```
mkdir downloads
cd downloads/
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-2.7.tar.gz
tar -vxf gsl-2.7.tar.gz
cd gsl-2.7
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I then re-ran and ArchR installed successfully.

```
devtools::install_github("GreenleafLab/ArchR", ref="master", repos = BiocManager::repositories())
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "in terminal?" Is this rtools 43 bash? I tried this there and can't get the "wget" step to work- "-bash: wget: command not found" I have no idea how or whether to use rtools or install (?) commands on it